# spring integration : response message not sent to client from error-channel

Tags: response, spring-integration, channel

I've the understanding that Spring Integration (SI) will wrap any exception (under the SI domain) to a MessageException instance and place it on the "error-channel".

Following are few snippets from my spring config file :

```
<int:channel-interceptor pattern="ersServiceReqRcvPostValidationChannel,ersServiceResRcvPostValidationChannel" order="1">
    <bean class="com.bnym.ecs.report.service.orchestration.interceptors.MsgJSONSyntaxValidationInterceptor"/>
</int:channel-interceptor>

<int:channel-interceptor pattern="ersServiceReqRcvPostValidationChannel,ersServiceResRcvPostValidationChannel" order="2">
    <bean class="com.bnym.ecs.report.service.orchestration.interceptors.MsgMetaDataValidationInterceptor"/>
</int:channel-interceptor>

<!--  Gateways -->
<int:gateway id="ersServiceReqRcvGateway"
    service-interface="com.bnym.ecs.report.service.orchestration.gateway.ERSOrchestrationSvcReqGateway"
    error-channel="reqRcvExceptionHandlerChannel">
    <int:method name="processRequest" request-channel="ersServiceReqRcvPostValidationChannel" />
</int:gateway>

<!--  Chain to handle all incoming request *after* doing all validations -->
<int:chain input-channel="ersServiceReqRcvPostValidationChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="msgReqAuditDetailDAOIntegrator" method="persist" />
    <!--  Router -->
    <int:router ref="ersServiceReqRcvRouter" />
</int:chain>

<!--  6) Pass the message through ERS svc to Exec svc ADH chain - Chain2 -->
<int:chain input-channel="ersSvc2execSvcQMRChannel" output-channel="ersServiceResRcvPostValidationChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="json2ObjTransformer" method="transformToERSOrchestrationSvcReq" />
    <int:service-activator ref="executionSvcReqMsgBuilder" method="getRptExecutionSvcReqForDataEngine" />
    <int:transformer ref="obj2JsonTransformer" method="transformFromRptExecutionSvcReqForDataEngine" />
    <int:service-activator ref="msgReqAuditDAOIntegrator" method="persist" />
    <int:service-activator ref="msgReqAuditDetailDAOIntegrator" method="persist" />
    <int:service-activator ref="executionSvcRESTStub" method="executeReportJSON" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="reqRcvExceptionHandlerChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="exceptionTransformer" method="handleError"/>
</int:chain>
```

The client makes a REST call to my implementation class which inturn places the received request on the Gateway defined in above spring config file

```
@Path("/reportExecutor")
public class ERSOrchestrationServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ReportInstanceDAO reportInstanceDAO;

    private static final ERSOrchestrationSvcDiagnosticLogger _logger = 
    ERSOrchestrationSvcDiagnosticLogger.getInstance(ERSOrchestrationServiceImpl.class);

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @POST
    @Path("/executeOnlineReport")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String executeOnlineReport(String jsonRequest) {

        ApplicationContext appCtx = SpringApplicationContextUtil.getApplicationContext();

        ERSOrchestrationSvcReqGateway ersOrchestrationSvcReqGateway = 
            (ERSOrchestrationSvcReqGateway) appCtx.getBean("ersServiceReqRcvGateway");

        Message<String> inputMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(jsonRequest)
                                                 .setHeader(ERSServiceConstants.KEY_MSG_CORRELATION_ID, correlationId)
                                                 .setHeader(ERSServiceConstants.KEY_MSG_REPORT_INSTANCE_ID, reportInstanceId)
                                                 .build();

        Message<String> returnMsg = ersOrchestrationSvcReqGateway.processRequest(inputMsg);
        return returnMsg.getPayload();

    }
```

As mentioned in above spring config file, the error-channel is read by a Transformer that creates a valid failed response message for the client and returns the message.

```
public class ErrorMessageUnwrapTransformer {

    @Autowired
    private Gson gsonUtil;
    @Autowired
    private ReportInstanceDAO reportInstanceDAO;
    @Autowired
    private ERSOrchestrationSvcFailedResMsgBuilder executionSvcFailedMsgBuilder;

    private static final ERSOrchestrationSvcDiagnosticLogger _log = 
    ERSOrchestrationSvcDiagnosticLogger.getInstance(ErrorMessageUnwrapTransformer.class); 

    @Transformer
    public Message<?> handleError(Message<?> message) {
        try{
            failedMsg = ((MessagingException) message.getPayload()).getFailedMessage();

            //some code logic to build a valid failed response message goes here
            Message<?> failedResponseMsg = executionSvcFailedMsgBuilder.getERSOrcSvcFailedResMsg(failedMsg );

            return failedResponseMsg;
        }
```

All seems to work fine when I get an exception, i.e., the exception is wrapped as MessagingException, put on the error-channel, the Transformer is able to read the channel, get failedMessage out of it, able to create a valid failed response message and return it.

However, the only issue I get is the call does not go back to the caller. In other words, the handle does not go back to the following code that had initiated the processing flow:

```
Message<String> returnMsg = ersOrchestrationSvcReqGateway.processRequest(inputMsg);
```

Can someone pls let me know why is the message returned by error-channel-read-Transformer not returning back to the class that invoked the Gateway method ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem Have you solved his?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here that you return the entire `Message<?>` from the `transformer`. This one is a component which doesn't care about headers, when the returned object is `Message<?>` already. You should worry about them on your own, like copy all headers from the `failedMsg` to your own `failedResponseMsg`.

Why is that so important?

Since you use `request/reply` gateway you are expecting for the return on that method invocation, something on the background ensure that for you. And it is a classical `replyChannel` algorithm.

Any `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` sends its result to the `replyChannel`, if you don't have an `outputChannel` configured, like your `reqRcvExceptionHandlerChannel` `<chain>` here.

With other components we can rely on the `copy-header-from-request` function, but not here with the `<transformer>`.

From other side `ErrorMessage` may be created in some context where we don't have headers, but we exactly may have the `failedMessage` in the `MessagingException` for which the `ErrorMessage` has been caused. So, we have to ensure `headers` from that `failedMessage`.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: In one sentence, you have to set the headers for the processor to identify and process the messages.