# Spring Integration: Mail error and HTTP gateway response

Tags: email, spring-integration

My use case is simple. I want to handle an exception caused by a system being unreachable, perform a retry based upon a configured retry policy, send an email when the retry threshold has been met, and return a custom response back the caller.

The challenges I am facing is that I cannot both send an email and return a response back to the caller. Since I was using a `int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter` initially, I would expect this behavior since this is a one-way component:

```
    <int:chain input-channel="defaultErrorChannel"> 
        <int:service-activator id="mailMessageActivator" expression="@mailHandler.process(payload)" />
        <int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter mail-sender="mailSender" />
    </int:chain>
```

However, if I introduce a `int-amqp:outbound-gateway` in front of the `int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter` (see the `Error Handling` config below), I would expect to be able to invoke a `int:service-activator` to construct and return a response to the caller.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? I see that someone else had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16894292/1990536) which is still unanswered. Both of the configurations I mentioned send emails, but always block from the caller without receiving a response upon timeout.

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration:

**Gateway**

```
<int:gateway id="customerGateway" service-interface="com.uscs.crm.integration.CustomerGateway" 
        default-request-channel="syncCustomers" default-reply-channel="replySyncCustomers" default-reply-timeout="30000">           
</int:gateway>      

<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="syncCustomers" output-channel="outboundRequestChannel" />    

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="outboundRequestChannel" reply-channel="replySyncCustomers"
              url="http://voorhees148.uscold.com:9595/web/customerSync/createCustomer"
              http-method="POST"
              rest-template="restTemplate"
              expected-response-type="com.uscs.crm.model.CustSyncResponseVO" 
              mapped-request-headers="Authorization, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession" />
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

**Error Handling**

```
    <int:channel id="defaultErrorChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="errorResponses"/>

    <!-- 
      ExponentialBackOffPolicy.multipler is applied to wait time over each retry attempt
      with a ExponentialBackOffPolicy.maximum configured.        
    -->
    <bean id="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
        <property name="retryTemplate">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
                <property name="backOffPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                        <property name="initialInterval" value="2000" />    
                        <property name="multiplier" value="2" />            
                        <property name="maxInterval" value="30000"/>        
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="retryPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                        <property name="maxAttempts" value="3"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="recoveryCallback">
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
                <constructor-arg ref="defaultErrorChannel"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="custSyncResponseHandler" class="com.uscs.crm.integration.handler.CustSyncResponseHandler"></bean>
    <int:chain input-channel="defaultErrorChannel" output-channel="replySyncCustomers"> 
        <int:service-activator id="mailMessageActivator" expression="@mailHandler.process(payload)" />
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="ERROR_ID" expression="T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()"/>
        </int:header-enricher>          
        <int-amqp:outbound-gateway
            exchange-name="error-responses-exchange"
            routing-key-expression="'error.response.'+headers.ERROR_ID"
            amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />
        <!-- Will this service-activator return a response to the caller (int:gateway) using channel `replySyncCustomers`? -->  
        <int:service-activator id="custSyncResponseActivator" expression="@custSyncResponseHandler.process(payload)" />             
    </int:chain>        

    <int-amqp:inbound-gateway queue-names="error-responses" request-channel="errorResponses"  
            connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" acknowledge-mode="AUTO" />

    <int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter channel="errorResponses" mail-sender="mailSender" />

    <!-- (Outbound Channel Adapter/Gateway) rabbit exchanges, queues, and bindings used by this app -->
    <rabbit:topic-exchange name="error-responses-exchange" auto-delete="false" durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="error-responses" pattern="error.response.*"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:topic-exchange>
    <rabbit:queue name="error-responses" auto-delete="false" durable="true"/>
```

---

***SOLUTION***: *I was able to get this working with help from @Artem. Below are the changes I made.*

**Service Activator Implementation** (handling `ErrorMessage`)

The key is the line which returns the reconstructed `Message` with all of the header information from the `ErrorMessage`.

```
@Override
public Message<CustSyncResponseVO> process(Message<MessagingException> errorMessage) {

    MessagingException errorException = errorMessage.getPayload();

    CustSyncResponseVO custSyncResponse = new CustSyncResponseVO();
    custSyncResponse.setResponseMessage(ExceptionUtils
            .convertToString(errorMessage.getPayload()));

    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(custSyncResponse)
        .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getHeaders())
        .copyHeadersIfAbsent(errorException.getFailedMessage().getHeaders()).build();

}
```

**Service Activator Config**

Used SpEL to reference the `#root` context to retrieve the `ErrorMessage` instead of the default which would be `MessagingException` (`payload`) and passed it to my `process` method on the POJO.

```
    <bean id="custSyncResponseHandler" class="com.uscs.crm.integration.handler.CustSyncResponseHandler" />        
    <int:chain id="errorGatewayResponseChain" input-channel="defaultErrorChannel" output-channel="replySyncCustomers">
        <int:service-activator id="custSyncResponseActivator" expression="@custSyncResponseHandler.process(#root)" />
    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see reason to introduce the AMQP middleware complexity there just for sending email in the end.

What only you need is `<publish-subscribe-channel id="defaultErrorChannel">` with to endpoints as subscribers to it.

The first one is one-way email sending `<chain>` and the second one is `custSyncResponseActivator` to reply something to your `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

You can find more info on the matter in the Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel).

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes complete sense. I will try that out and let you know how it works out.

Comment: I created a `chain` for the `service-activator` and needed to add back the `replyChannel` header attribute: `<int:header name=\"replyChannel\" ref=\"replySyncCustomers\"/>`. When I do that, I am stuck in an infinite loop, but I see the response being delivered to `replyCustSyncCustomers` channel. The `outbound-gateway` does not seem to consume the reply. Eventually, I receive a `StackOverflowError` on the client.

Comment: Well, you should build your custom reply message based on the `ErrorMessage.payload.getFailedMessage()`. Especially utilize its `headers`, where you can find `replyChannel` in face of `TemporaryReplyChannel` for the `customerGateway`. The `reply-channel` on the `gateway` uses that `replyChannel` anyway to deliver reply to the gateway.

Comment: Answered that question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894292/spring-integration-response-message-not-sent-to-client-from-error-channel/34445144#34445144

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped a lot. I was able to get this to work. Posting my implementation here so it may help someone else.